# MSBuild RecursiveDir is empty

Tags: msbuild, copy, msbuild-4.0

I'm trying to make a custom MSBuild script to build all solutions in our repository:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SourceHome Condition=" '$(SourceHome)'=='' ">..\</SourceHome>
        <ToolsHome Condition=" '$(ToolsHome)'=='' ">.\Tools\</ToolsHome>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='' ">Release</Configuration>
        <DestFolder Condition=" '$(DestFolder)'=='' ">.\$(Configuration)\</DestFolder>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <AllSolutions Include="$(SourceHome)**\*.sln"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Default" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Build;Assemble"/>

    <Target Name="Clean">
        <Message Text="Cleaning projects..."/>
        <MSBuild Projects="@(AllSolutions)"
             Targets="Clean"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);"/>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="RestorePackages">
        <Message Text="Restoring packages..."/>
        <Exec Command="echo y| &quot;$(ToolsHome)NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;%(AllSolutions.Identity)&quot;"/>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
        <Message Text="Building projects..."/>
        <MSBuild Projects="@(AllSolutions)"
                 ContinueOnError="true"
                 Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
            <Output ItemName="OutputFiles" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
        </MSBuild>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Assemble">
        <Message Text="Assembling output..."/>
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(DestFolder)"/>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(OutputFiles)"
              DestinationFiles="@(OutputFiles->'$(DestFolder)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

The script works well except for the last copy task where %(RecursiveDir) evaluates to an empty string, putting all files in the root destination folder... I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

I found [MSBuild ITaskItem RecursiveDir metadata disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070569/msbuild-itaskitem-recursivedir-metadata-disappears) but it doesn't seem to apply here...

I also found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/5266a9a6-78e1-45d5-9302-d5c4577853ec/copy-msbuild-task-recursivedir-is-empty) and [this](http://mikefourie.wordpress.com/2007/06/07/braces-break-recursivedir-in-msbuild/) thread but there are no double slashes or braces in any paths. Heres an example of the output during the copy task:

> Copying file from
>   "x:\my\repo\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\bin\Release\Example.dll" to
>   ".\Release\Example.dll".

Answer (score 1):

Even though the `AllSolutions` items have [RecursiveDir metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx) populated because of the `**` wildcard in your code, the [MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) is not populating `RecursiveDir` in the `OutputFiles` items. The `TargetOutputs` are placed into a single array, with full paths but no `RecursiveDir` metadata.

Comment: So is the solution to not use Output and instead just create a new ItemGroup with the files to copy in the Assembly task??